# Compute derivative of real valued tensor function (second invariant)

Tags: derivatives, tensors, classical-mechanics

In the context of continuum mechanics, given a tensor $A$, the second invariant $i_2(A) = \frac{\text{tr}(A)^2 - \text{tr}(A^2)}{2} $. I need to compute its derivative $Di_2(A)[S]$ (I'm using the notation from Gurtin's book - *An introduction to continuum mechanics*), where $S$ is a tensor.
([see here for better comprehension](https://books.google.it/books?id=W-0b09yIgq4C&pg=PA26&hl=it&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false))
I will analyize one term at a time:

- $D\text{tr}(A)^2[S] = 2\text{tr}(A)[D \text{tr}(A)[S]] = 2 \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(S)$
- $D\text{tr}(A^2)[S] = \text{tr}[DA^2[S]] = \text{tr}(AS+ SA)$

where I used the fact that $D \text{tr}(A)[S] = \text{tr}(S)$ because the **trace is a linear operator**.

So I would obtain $$D i_2(A)[S] = \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(S)  - \frac{1}{2} \text{tr}(AS+SA)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is right, though for the second term, your notation is misleading. Taken literally, $D\text{tr}(A^2)[S]$ means the derivative of trace at the point $A^2$ evaluated on $S$. This would just equal $\text{tr}(S)$, since trace is linear. Though, what you meant is that
\begin{align}
D\left(A\mapsto \text{tr}(A^2)\right)_A[S] &= [(D\text{tr}_{A^2})\circ \left(D(A\mapsto A^2)_A\right)][S]\tag{chain rule}\\
&= \text{tr}(AS + SA).
\end{align}
Here, I put the point of evaluation of derivatives in subscript to avoid excessive bracketing.

This is just one of those issues which comes up over and over in differential calculus, about functions vs function values.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not agree when you said "point $A^2$. The trace is a (linear) operator that maps tensors to scalars, so the taken argument is a tensor, not a point, right @peek-a-boo?

Comment: @Vefhug trace is a certain type of function (particularly, a linear transformation defined on some vector space mapping into $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, depending on the field) and $A^2$ is an element in the domain of this function. SO, it is perfectly reasonable to call $A^2$ a "point". For example, if I consider the space $X= C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$ of smooth real-functions, then an element of $X$ is a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ which is smooth. But, it is perfectly reasonable (and common) to call $f$ a "point" in the space $X$, and write $f\in X$, just like how we'd write $(0,1)\in\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: My guess is that you have a disposition to reserve the term "point" for an element of $\Bbb{R}^3$ or maybe $\Bbb{R}^n$, but there is no need to restrict terminology like this. Sometimes, it pays off to think of more complicated objects (like functions/tensors etc) as being "points", but just points in a space other than $\Bbb{R}^n$. However, what I'm curious about is how are you defining the square of a tensor $A$? Do you mean the tensor product $A\otimes A$, but are just omitting the $\otimes$ symbol?

Comment: I see your point (lol): in my previous Banach spaces courses I was used to call elements of the space $X$ "points". To answer your question, to me the tensor $A^2 = A \circ A$. In practice, what is important how it acts on vectors: $A^2 =A(Av)$ which is well defined because $Av$ is a vector

Comment: Oh I see, so you're considering very special tensors (endomorphisms on a vector space). Yea, ok anyway, it doesn't matter whether for the differentiation whether we use $\circ$ or $\otimes$, the formulas will look identical, because the product rule works quite generally with any bilinear operation on finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: I'd like to check my argument for this key part: $[(D\text{tr}_{A^2})\circ \left(D(A\mapsto A^2)_A\right)][S]$. I need a check on my steps in the chain rule. More specifically, I want to be formally correct:

The expressio is the following
$$D(A \mapsto tr(A^2))[S]=D(A \mapsto \text{tr}(A))_{A^2} [D(A \mapsto A^2)_A[S]] = \text{tr}[AS + SA] = \text{tr}(AS+SA)$$ because $\text{tr}$ is a linear operator. As you can see, I wrote the subscript $A$, which is the *point* of evaluation, and then I let the result act on $S$. Is everything right? @peek-a-bo

Comment: @Vefhug yes that's right (though before the equal sign, you forgot to indicate the subscript $A$).

Comment: You're right! Thanks for your answer and your comments @peek-a-boo